# I need to remove this deadbolt but it's not coming off

Tags: doors, deadbolt

I'm removing an old Kwikset deadbolt circa 1995 I got the handle set part out but this deadbolt has some type of protective casing and the front is not coming off nor the back.

Here's the back side.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is a double cylinder deadbolt (has key cylinder on both sides). Use a flathead screwdriver to remove the two black bolts.

[image]

Comment: Figured that out about 5 min ago. Didn't look like those were bolts. Wish I tried before I damaged the door :(